# Warning: session_destroy(): Trying to destroy uninitialized session with phpCas

Tags: php, symfony, cas, phpcas

I am facing a problem today with the phpCas library https://wiki.jasig.org/display/CASC/phpCAS.

Problem is the following, when I try to use some logout function, I got the message

```
Warning: session_destroy(): Trying to destroy uninitialized session
```

After giving a quick look into the phpCas's library code, I manage to figure out where the problem comes from, here is a snippet of a logout function :

```
session_write_close();
header('Location: '.$cas_url);
phpCAS::trace("Prepare redirect to : ".$cas_url);
session_unset();
session_destroy();
```

The problem there it seems is that `session_write_close()` actually close the session then `session_destroy()` can't work.

Tried to put the `session_write_close()` in comment and worked like a charm but it leads to two questions :

- Is the problem really coming from there? Or should it work?
- If the problem do really come from there, why is it there and nobody complaining? Thought phpCas was a reknown library used by many.

Comment: Why is the **symfony2** tag in your question? Because sf2 doesn't handle the sessions like this.

Comment: Because I'm using symfony2 and thought the bug might be in relation (even if it seems not)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you checked out the master branch (2af859ff76) - just checked and it does have an error in it.  You should:

- Check out one of the release branches, like 1.3-stable
- Log this bug with the author

Comment: Thank you very much. Thought it could be a bug from their code at the first place, and then the fact that last update was at least a month ago and nobody complaining made me thing I should be wrong. I thought phpCas was a bit more popular.

Answer (score 0):

As the manual suggests that "**session_write_close — Write session data and end session**" So you are getting fair warning. as Session has been closed already.

[FYI](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-write-close.php)

Comment: Didn't I say that in the question?

Comment: Yes so remove the session_write_close()

Comment: Have you read the question? The code is not mine, it's from the phpCas library...

Answer (score 0):

you need session_start(); before you can destroy it

also header("Location ...) is sending out headers so you can't close the session afterwards. do the redirect after closing the session

Comment: Did you even took the time to read the already given answers and comments on them?