# PHP session destroy Trying to destroy uninitialized session

Tags: php, session

I've read several topics like:

[Error — session_destroy() — Trying to destroy uninitialized session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18551030/error-session-destroy-trying-to-destroy-uninitialized-session), [Warning: session_destroy(): Trying to destroy uninitialized session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18188716/warning-session-destroy-trying-to-destroy-uninitialized-session), [Warning: session_destroy(): Trying to destroy uninitialized session with phpCas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17522574/warning-session-destroy-trying-to-destroy-uninitialized-session-with-phpcas)

And none of them help me.

```
public function forbidden(){
    if(!isset($_SESSION)){ session_start(); }

    if(!isset($_SESSION['email']) || !isset($_SESSION['id'])){
        $this->error_404();
    }else{

        if(!isset($_COOKIE['data'])){
            session_destroy();
            $this->error_404();
        }

        if($_COOKIE['data'] != sha1($_SESSION['email'])){
            session_destroy();
            unset($_COOKIE["data"]);
            setcookie("data", false, time() - 3600, '/');
            $this->error_404();
        }
    }
}
```

> Warning: session_destroy() [function.session-destroy]: Trying to
>   destroy uninitialized session

I do receive that error on the second `session_destroy();`, the session is initialized so I don't get it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Read This Answers of this question  on stackoverflow

[why session destroy not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6472123/why-session-destroy-not-working)

put this code in first and End of Your php File

```
<?php
ob_start();
?>
Your Code Here...
<?php
ob_flush();
?>
```

Your calling session_destroy() twice.

Or Removed All Sessions on server...

Comment: I actually use that function in my files but I forgot to use in this file. It solved. Thanks.

Comment: I'm thank . i write this on community wiki mode.And your Accept not give rank for me . please voet this Later... ;)

Answer (score 0):

You're calling `session_destroy()` twice.

If your cookie isn't set, then it won't equal `$_SESSION['email']` will it?

Change your code to:

```
public function forbidden(){
    if(!isset($_SESSION)){ session_start(); }

    if(!isset($_SESSION['email']) || !isset($_SESSION['id'])){
        $this->error_404();
    }else{

        if(!isset($_COOKIE['data'])){
            session_destroy();
            $this->error_404();
        } elseif($_COOKIE['data'] != sha1($_SESSION['email'])){
            session_destroy();
            unset($_COOKIE["data"]);
            setcookie("data", false, time() - 3600, '/');
            $this->error_404();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I've changed totally the code to what you've told me and I keep receiving the same error in the same line (in the second `session_destory()`).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you call session destroy twice. If `$_COOKIE['data']` is not set, then `$_COOKIE['data'] != sha1($_SESSION['email'])` will return `false` as well and it will try to destroy the session again.

```
    if(!isset($_COOKIE['data'])){
        session_destroy();
        $this->error_404();
    }

    if($_COOKIE['data'] != sha1($_SESSION['email'])){
        session_destroy();
        unset($_COOKIE["data"]);
        setcookie("data", false, time() - 3600, '/');
        $this->error_404();
    }
```

Make the checks on in another

```
     if($_COOKIE['data'] != sha1($_SESSION['email'])){
        if(!isset($_COOKIE['data'])){
        session_destroy();
        $this->error_404();
        }
        else
        {
        unset($_COOKIE["data"]);
        setcookie("data", false, time() - 3600, '/');
        session_destroy();
        $this->error_404();
        }
    }
```

If the cookie data is not valid, it may be because there is no cookie. This way, if it's not valid, it checks if it exists. If it does exist and it's not valid, it does something. If it doesn't, it does something else.